# How to modify state of a redux store from a reducer

Tags: javascript, react-redux

Below is a reducer written by me:

```
function rootReducer(state = rootInitialState, action) {
  const appleState = _.cloneDeep(state.get('apple') || {});
  const orangeState = _.cloneDeep(state.get('orange') || {});

switch(action.type){
case 'appleAction':
  return state.set('apple', action.appleChanges);

case 'orangeAction':
  return state.set('orange', action.orangeChanges);
}

default:
  return state;
}
```

What if I have an action.type == 'both' and which wants to modify both 'apple' and 'orange' in state, then how would I return the modified state?

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
case 'both':
return Object.assign({}, state, { apple: action.appleChanges, orange: action.orangeChanges });
```